# How to configure newrelic agent in a python application?

Tags: newrelic

I ran scripts in python with `python3 myscript.py`.

I added the newrelic lib via `pip install` and generated the `newrelic.ini`. But when executing the script, do I just execute it with the `newrelic-admin` wrapper script in front of it? Something like:

`newrelic-admin run-program python3 myscript.py`?

I tried that but I have not been able to see the app in newrelic UI.

I tested the python agent test by running `newrelic-admin validate-config` and was able to see the `Python Agent Test` app in the newrelic UI (after ~5min).

Comment: What did you try doing? What is the error you are facing?

Comment: I did not see the app in newrelic UI

Comment: But when executing the script do I specify I just execute it as newrelic-admin run-program python3 myscript.py? This sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Uttam updated, let me know.